# Make image height auto adjust to text height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given this HTML

```
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="">
  </div>

  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis facilisis nisi elit, vitae interdum nisi porttitor a. Maecenas porta mollis venenatis. Proin suscipit, est et malesuada ultricies, nisi elit aliquam arcu, et luctus felis dolor euismod ante. Praesent nec malesuada arcu. Nunc rutrum erat risus, id elementum leo dignissim eu. Fusce feugiat, massa vestibulum venenatis ullamcorper, nisl justo aliquam purus, nec pellentesque tellus magna non quam. Pellentesque luctus quam in justo congue tempor. Cras placerat sit amet nulla id pretium. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dictum neque sed lacus congue, vel dapibus enim efficitur.
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I make the image height scale automatically with the text div, according to browser width and font size of the text?

1. https://jsfiddle.net/msuL6pvx/ In this case the image has to be scaled down to have the same height as the text
2. https://jsfiddle.net/msuL6pvx/1/ In this case the image has to be enlarged to its max size (300x300) and not exceed those dimensions

Comment: text always have 50 % of total width?

Comment: @Sohrab that wont keep the aspect ratio though. The image should always be shown as a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' think this is possible with pure CSS. The only think I could think of is using `position: absolute` for `<img>` to take it out of the flow in combination with max-height; then adjusting the margin of the text with javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/zphb0fLd/

Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as my knowledge, the image size can be increased with relative to text size, but its opposite case is not possible.

Here is my code. I use the flexbox to increase the height of the image as per text size. Let me know if it meets your requirements.

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="text-container">
    <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis facilisis nisi elit, vitae interdum nisi porttitor a. Maecenas porta mollis venenatis. Proin suscipit, est et malesuada ultricies, nisi elit aliquam arcu, et luctus felis dolor euismod ante. Praesent nec malesuada arcu. Nunc rutrum erat risus, id elementum leo dignissim eu. Fusce feugiat, massa vestibulum venenatis ullamcorper, nisl justo aliquam purus, nec pellentesque tellus magna non quam. Pellentesque luctus quam in justo congue tempor. Cras placerat sit amet nulla id pretium. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dictum neque sed lacus congue, vel dapibus enim efficitur.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;

}
.image-container{
  flex:1;
}
.text-container{
  flex:3;
}
.text-container p{
  font-size:2em;
  padding:10px;
}
.image-container img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

Live example link: https://codepen.io/pranaysharma995/pen/JjdQWyQ